# Вывести строку с минимальным временем из таблицы по условию SQL

Tags: sql

мне нужно вывести одну строку с самым ранним временем, а выходят все равно все 4 строки, что я делаю не так?

```
select N_KDK, DATE_IN, MIN(TIME_IN) as min, PR_EXIT, KZEP_IN from ZTAE_ 
where N_KDK = 3376 AND DATE_IN = '01.21.2020'
group by N_KDK, DATE_IN, TIME_IN, PR_EXIT, KZEP_IN
```

[image]

Comment: время лучше хранить unix формате тогда будет проще с ним работать в запросах

Comment: ORDER BY min ASC LIMIT 1

Comment: Зачем вам группировки?

Comment: @CrazyElf если не задаю группировку то выдает ошибку  Column 'ZTAE_.N_KDK' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: @DrMcSheen Incorrect syntax near 'limit'. 
я попробовал сделать через top, то же самое)

Comment: @thegamestarted Если вам нужна просто одна запись, то делаете select всех полей без всяких аггрегатных функций from ... where ... order by TIME_IN ASC и всё. А вот как ограничить одной записью - это зависит от базы. В MS SQL это будет SELECT TOP 1 и далее остальной запрос. В MySql будет через LIMIT. Какая у вас база? Лучше прямо  меткой укажите. SQL не универсален, детали зависят от конкретной БД.

Comment: @CrazyElf действительно, получилось вывести так одну строку, но парадокс в том что это не самая ранняя дата, строка даты видать символьного значения поэтому время 7 и 9 часов не считываются первыми т.к. нет нуля впереди, сперва идут 11 и 17))) но все равно спасибо
вывел через top1

Answer (score 0):

Я объединил столбцы даты и времени для то чтобы вывести одну строку с самым ранним временем

```
select TOP 1 n_kdk, min(date_in + ' ' + time_in) date_time,PR_EXIT, kzep_in from ZTAE_ 
where N_KDK = '   3376' AND DATE_IN = '01.21.2020'
group by pr_exit, n_kdk,kzep_in
```

[image]

Comment: И всё-равно непонятно, зачем вам группировка. Ну то есть так можно, конечно, но группировка нужна для того, чтобы аггрегировать данные *внутри каждой группы*, а вы этими группами всё-равно не пользуетесь.